# Testing with Mocha using Express and Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a project where my Gruntfile sets up an Express server. Now I want to start testing with Mocha, but it keeps returning the same error. I don't really know how to solve the problem.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
// Express Config
    express: {
        options: {
          // Override defaults here
        },
        dev: {
            options: {
                script: 'app.js'
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 3001,
                script: 'test/testapp.js'
            }
        }
    },

    mocha: {
        all: {
            src: ['test/views/*.html'],
            options: {
                run: true
            }
        }
    },

    // Open Config
    open: {
        dev: {
            path: 'http://localhost:3000'
        },
        test: {
            path: 'http://localhost:3001'
        }
    },

//Test
grunt.registerTask('test', 'Run the tests.', [
    'clean:server',
    'jshint:test',
    'express:test',
    'open:test',
    'mocha'
]);
```

My testapp file loads an instance of an Express server. It look like this:

**test/testapp.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('jade').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    req.render('index.html');
})

// start up server
var PORT = 3001;

var server = http.createServer( app ).listen( PORT, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + PORT);
} );
```

This is the HTML testfile:

**test/views/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mocha Spec Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
    <script src="node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script>
        var assert = chai.assert;
        var expect = chai.expect;
        var should = chai.should();
    </script>

    <!-- include source files here... -->

    <!-- include spec files here... -->
    <script src="../spec/test.js"></script>

    <script>mocha.run()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test/spec/test.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('Give it some context', function () {
  describe('maybe a bit more context here', function () {
    it('should run here few assertions', function () {

    });
  });
});
```

When I run `grunt test` it gives me this error:

```
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "jshint:test" (jshint) task
>> 2 files lint free.

Running "express:test" (express) task
Starting background Express server
Express server listening on port 3001

Running "open:test" (open) task

Running "mocha:all" (mocha) task
Testing: test/views/index.html

Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: quick first impression: sounds like mocha is not being loaded if describe is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in severals parts :

**PART 1**

```
describe not defined
```

was due to a miss configuration of the grunt task express:test (grunt-express-server). The script defined in the Gruntfile.js was tests.js. When trying to reach localhost:3000 the error occured.
Solved by target a server-like script in the gruntfile.js : test/testapp.js

**PART 2**

```
Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue.
```

Error when loading the test/views/index.html page. Solved by using grunt-mocha-phantomjs instead of grunt-mocha

Comment: I have installed `grunt-mocha`, `mocha` and `chai` via npm. They are all in my node_modules folder. In my Gruntfile I use: `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);`

Comment: when you run mocha -b path/to/test.js what does it tell you ?

Comment: It looks like the function inside test.js is executed before mocha.run().
the function is self-executed when loaded.

Comment: Can you give us you full Gruntfile.js ?

Comment: What kind of script should I target in the express:test task?

Comment: I think, according to the github page, that you should target a server.js file which launch you app.

Comment: I got rid of the first error. Now I've got only `PhantomJS TimeOut` that's remaining. I've edited my question.

Comment: I fixed it by using `grunt-mocha-phantomjs` plugin instead of `grunt-mocha`.

Comment: Nice ! I was able to reproduce but i have nit been able to look for a solution. Problem solved then ?

Comment: Yes, totally solved! Maybe for clarity you can add something to your answer about `grunt-mocha-phantomjs`